# How to iterate collection in XAML, where the collection is part of the model in c# class

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, desktop-application

I am building desktop application using WPF and XAML with MVVM pattern.
I have a collection of strings ( error messages) in the model class. Class is binded to the XAML. I need to iterate the collection of strings so that they are displayed in bullet points in the view.

I have tried itemscontrols tag, but no luck with it. It just displays the first element of the list.

I expected that collection will be iterated but only the first element of the collection is displayed. There are no error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to render a list of anything in WPF/MVVM is with an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />
```

If you don't like the default item representation then you can override the item template:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., StringFormat={}&#8226;{0}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Result:

[image]

You can also override the default ItemPanel if you want the items to be laid out different i.e. WrapPanel, horizontal StackPanel etc.